# Check for bound variables fails for K combinator

Tags: scheme, grammar, lambda-calculus, combinators

I recently got in possession of a copy of "Essentials of Programming Languages", second edition. At page 29, the book introduces the following Scheme-flavored grammar for lambda calculus:

```
<expression> ::= <identifier>
             ::= (lambda (<identifier>) <expression>)
             ::= (<expression> <expression>)
```

It then proceeds to introduce a definition (Definition 1.3.3, page 31) for free and bound variables, which reads:

```
A variable x occurs free in a lambda calculus expression E if and only if

1. E is a variable reference and E is the same as x; or
2. E is of the form (lambda (y) E'), where y is different from x and x occurs free in E'; or
3. E is of the form (E1 E2) and x occurs free in E1 or E2.

A variable x occurs bound in a lambda calculus expression E if and only if

1. E is of the form (lambda (y) E'), where x occurs bound in E' or x and y are the same variable and y occurs free in E'; or
2. E is of the form (E1 E2) and x occurs bound in E1 or E2.
```

Such a definition is then readily transformed in two Scheme procedures, named, resp., `occurs-free?` and `occurs-bound?`:

```
(define occurs-free?
  (lambda (var exp)
    (cond
      ((symbol? exp) (eqv? exp var))
      ((eqv? (car exp) 'lambda)
       (and (not (eqv? (caadr exp) var))
            (occurs-free? var (caddr exp))))
      (else (or (occurs-free? var (car exp))
                (occurs-free? var (cadr exp)))))))

(define occurs-bound?
  (lambda (var exp)
    (cond
      ((symbol? exp) #f)
      ((eqv? (car exp) 'lambda)
       (or (occurs-bound? var (caddr exp))
           (and (eqv? (caadr exp) var)
                (occurs-free? var (caddr exp)))))
      (else (or (occurs-bound? var (car exp))
                (occurs-bound? var (cadr exp)))))))
```

One would expect `occurs-bound?` to return `#t` when combinators (i.e., procedures only consisting of bound variables) are fed as input. However, the test fails for the K combinator:

```
> (occurs-bound? 'x '(lambda (c) (lambda (x) c)))
#f
```

This is because point 1. in the definition of bound variables, which states that for a variable to be bound it must be both quantified in a lambda and later appear free in its body. Since`x` is ignored in the body of the inner lambda, the test returns false.

Apparently, `occurs-bound?` is not presented in the third edition, so it is not possible to make any comparison with the most recent edition of the book.

Is the above definition flawed, or am I missing something? [Here's a repl for the code](https://repl.it/repls/HumiliatingEagerIdentifier).

Thank you

Comment: Note that in the definition, the names "x" and "y" are not variables but meta-variables; they range over lambda-variables. Hence the phrasing "x and y are *the same variable* and y occurs free in E'" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Good point. "Types and Programming Languages" is more precise in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it be flawed? What's the origin for your suspicions?

Does `'x` occur bound in `'(lambda (c) (lambda (y) c))`?

Does `'x` occur bound in `'(lambda (c) (lambda (z) c))`?

Does it seem strange to you that it doesn't? I would expect not. Why then should it be considered occurring bound in the *alpha-equivalent* `'(lambda (c) (lambda (x) c))`, then?

It shouldn't. It's not even there.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Admittely, I am not proficient in lambda calculus. My concerns are due to the fact that 1. Intuitively, a variable is said to be bound if it is quantified in a lambda, as it is `x` in `(lambda (c) (lambda (x) c))`; 2. the K combinator is, indeed, a combinator. Therefore, according to the very definition of combinator, it should not feature any free variable (this is also stated by the authors at page 30, _"Lambda calculus expressions without free variables are called combinators"_).

Comment: there is no `x` behind the `(lambda (x) ...)` there, so it is not bound - it is not even there. :) it *would* be bound if it *were* there.

Comment: what free variable do you see in there in the K combinator? just as you said, there isn't any. right? `c` is bound. that's it. it is bound precisely because it *does* appear free in the nested expression. in fact, "c is bound" is sloppy. the book takes care to say "`c` *appears* bound in ...". I remember having same doubts exactly for this thing, BTW. "It's bound by the lambda declaration" or something... "!???" But the question is not whether it "is bound", but whether it "*appears* bound". This helps to untangle the two, I think.

Comment: Let me rephrase to see if I get your argument: as the only variable in use (i.e., `c`) is bound, `(lambda (c) (lambda (x) c))` does indeed constitute a combinator, correct? The takehome message is that it makes sense to qualify variables as either bound or free only if they are in use.

Comment: the importance of this is, IIRC, in later beta- (or alpha- (?)) conversion manipulations: if no free (conversely: bound) variable in a given lambda-expression becomes bound (conversely: free), then the transformation is valid.

Comment: to your last question, yes. That would seem to follow the definition fully. so, yes, that's why they always make a point of saying "*appears* bound in ...", not the more vague "*is* bound in ...".